# C++ Appending vector of pointers inside member function of a class causing odd behaviour

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

In my C++ program I have a class with a member variable that is a vector of pointers to objects of another class. It also has a member function that is supposed to add an inputted object's reference to that vector of pointers and then print all the objects' names in the vector to make sure it works. I add `Obj1` and `Obj2` using this function and expect the console to output `Obj1` then `Obj1Obj2` but instead it outputs `Obj1` and then `Obj2Obj2`. Can someone explain why this happens and more importantly how to fix it?
I'm using Visual Studio 2015. Here is the code for the program.

```
using namespace std;

class MyClass1 {
public:
    string name;
    MyClass1(string a) {
        name = a;
    }
};
MyClass1 Obj1("Obj1");
MyClass1 Obj2("Obj2");

class MyClass2 {
public:
    vector<MyClass1*> vop;
    string name;
    MyClass2(string a) {
        name = a;
    }
    void addObjtoVec(MyClass1 mc) {
    vop.push_back(&mc);
    for (int i = 0; i < vop.size(); i++) {
        cout << vop[i]->name;
    }
    cout << endl;
    }
};

MyClass2 Obj3("Obj3");

int main() {
    Obj3.addObjtoVec(Obj1);
    Obj3.addObjtoVec(Obj2);
}
```

Comment: Replace `void addObjtoVec(MyClass1 mc) {` with `void addObjtoVec(MyClass1 *mc) {`, `vop.push_back(&mc);` with `vop.push_back(mc);`, `Obj3.addObjtoVec(Obj1);` with `Obj3.addObjtoVec(&Obj1);` and `Obj3.addObjtoVec(Obj2);` with `Obj3.addObjtoVec(&Obj2);`

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In addition to John's answer above, the problem stems from the fact that you are passing `Obj1` and `Obj2` by value. This means that the `addObjtoVec` function has a local copy of the variables which will go out of scope once the function returns. One way to fix this would be to change 'addObjtoVec' to receive a reference instead:

```
void addObjtoVec(MyClass& mc)
```

This means that the function is referencing your global declarations, rather than local copies.

Comment: You still want to fix storing pointers in the vector. This is a sure way to cause problems down the track - it is really just hiding the problem.

Answer (score 2):

You are pushing the address of local variables (parameters) into the vector. Once the local variable goes out of scope the pointer (which is still stored in your vector) is no valid anymore. Accessing it gives undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

```
void addObjtoVec(MyClass1 mc)
```

takes `mc` by value. This makes `mc` a local variable copy of the variable `addObjtoVec` was called with.

```
vop.push_back(&mc);
```

stores a pointer to `mc`, not the original variable, and being a local variable, `mc` will go out of scope at the end of `addObjtoVec`, leaving you with a vector full of pointers to Crom knows what. Basically `addObjtoVec` is an [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) generator. You do not know what is going to happen.

Solution:

Odds are very good that you don't need to store pointers in the `vector`.

```
vector<MyClass1> vop;
```

and later

```
vop.push_back(mc);
```

will eliminate the problem of `mc` going out of scope and any potential problems stemming from mixing pointers to statically and dynamically allocated `MyClass1`s in `vop`.

Example:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class MyClass1
{
public:
    std::string name;
    MyClass1(std::string a)
    {
        name = a;
    }
/*  consider using the member initializer list instead of initializing
 *  in the constructor body. It gives the compiler more optimization avenues
 *
    MyClass1(std::string a): (name(a)
    {
    }
 */
};

class MyClass2
{
public:
    std::vector<MyClass1> vop;
    std::string name;
    MyClass2(std::string a)
    {
        name = a;
    }
    void addObjtoVec(MyClass1 mc)
    {
        vop.push_back(mc);
        for (int i = 0; i < vop.size(); i++)
        {
            std::cout << vop[i].name;
        }
/* consider using C++11 enhanced for loop when you want to iterate an entire container
        for (MyClass1 & elem: vop)
        {
            std::cout << elem.name;
        }
 */

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyClass2 Obj3("Obj3");
    Obj3.addObjtoVec(MyClass1("Obj1"));
    Obj3.addObjtoVec(MyClass1("Obj2"));
}
```

If you must use pointers, change the definition of `addObjtoVec` to

```
void addObjtoVec(MyClass1 & mc)
```

to pass `mc` by reference.

You will have to sort out ownership of the of the pointers and who is responsible for deletion on your own.